# System will only boot into a Live CD with core disabled in BIOS and ACPI off

Tags: cpu, bios, acpi, kernel-panic

I have a system that was running a Q6600 and Windows 7 RC. It crashed last night into a BSOD with a MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION. Now it does that every time it boots into Windows.

I tried using my Ubuntu Live CD, but the kernel would error out, the stack trace showed something along the linse of "Can not synchronized to one of the CPUs".

Working from this, I enabled the "Limit CPU to 3 cores" option in my BIOS and tried again. This time, it seemed to have died after an ACPI call, so I disabled that during the boot and now it is running from the Ubuntu Live CD, showing 2 cores.

Does anyone here think I have any hope or is it simply a CPU waiting to die?

EDIT: 1 core now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION is almost always a hardware fault, and usually points to a failing CPU or motherboard.  These may be failing due to power supply failures/under-power as well.

Based on the fact you're having trouble booting Linux as well it's not going to be a driver issue.

If you have any tweaked setting in your BIOS (i.e.: you're overclocking) turn it all back to defaults.  If it still does it, you're probably going to have to start swapping new hardware to identify the culprit.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the CPU.